# PHP inside background url CSS

Tags: background-image

I would like to know if there's a way to insert PHP code inside a `background-image:url('CODE PHP HERE')`.

I am using qTranslate inside my wordpress and what i want is to use a different background for an input form based on the language i am using. One input background for french and a different one for spanish using qtranslate shortcode.

Here is what i would like to do :
in PHP : `[:en]/url/imgFR.png[:de]/url/imgES.png`

inside my CSS : `background-image:url('CODE PHP HERE')`

When i do this, it doesn't show anything :

```
background-image:url('<?php _e('[:fr]/url/imgFR.png[:es]/url/imgES.png'); ?>')
```

Help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you could do is put the css directly in your header file (not in a seperate css file).
This way you can simply do the following in the header file:

```
<style>background-image:url('<?php _e('[:fr]/url/imgFR.png[:es]/url/imgES.png'); ?>');</style>
```